# find and replace wildcard strings in large text files with sed

Tags: html, text, sed

I need to replace large swaths of HTML in a 5MB file, and all the OS X editors I've tried hang on attempting this. sed seems to be the answer, but writing the correct command is failing me. I've been at this 3 hours, and finally asking for help!

Here's an example - all of this

`</div><div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined<br>Added by **Tiffany Seibel-Howard** on <abbr title="**Thursday, June 20, 2013 at 12:39am**" data-utime="**1371703149**"><span class="timestampContent">**June 20, 2013**</span></abbr></div></div><div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></td><td class="_51m- vTop hLeft pam _51mw"><div class="_4-u2 _4-u8" data-name="GroupProfileGridItem" data-testid="GroupMember_**100002558935125**"><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8r lfloat _ohe" href="**https://www.facebook.com/brookesblossoms?fref=grp_mmbr_list**" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?**id=100002558935125&amp;extragetparams=%7B%22fref%22%3A%22grp_mmbr_list%22%2C%22directed_target_id%22%3A479810992099587%7D**" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1"><img class="_s0 _rv img" src="./(2) Neuroblastoma Support group . You are Not Alone Ask Away._files/**10374531_827398764022080_7090816591123160699_n.jpg**" alt=""></a><div class="_8u _42ef"><div class="_6a _5u5j"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:100px"></div><div class="_6a _5u5j _6b"><div class="fsl fwb fcb">`

Needs to be deleted, any time it shows up in the file.

Any of the pieces in there between ** and ** are wildcards that will change throughout the file.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with what you are trying to do is that you have text containing regexp metacharacters (e.g. `?`) that you need to treat as literal but you also have literal text that you need to convert to regexp metacharacters (e.g. `>**June 20, 2013**<` -> `>[^<]+<`). To do that, you're going to want to start by first figuring out how to express the parts of your text that are changeable as uniquely descriptive strings, e.g.:

```
</div><div class="fsm fwn fcg">Joined<br>Added by _NOT_LESS_THAN_ on <abbr title="_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_" data-utime="_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_"><span class="timestampContent">_NOT_LESS_THAN_</span></abbr></div></div><div class="_4bl7 mrm"></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></td><td class="_51m- vTop hLeft pam _51mw"><div class="_4-u2 _4-u8" data-name="GroupProfileGridItem" data-testid="GroupMember__NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_"><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8r lfloat _ohe" href="_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/user.php?_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_" data-hovercard-prefer-more-content-show="1"><img class="_s0 _rv img" src="./(2) Neuroblastoma Support group . You are Not Alone Ask Away._files/_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_" alt=""></a><div class="_8u _42ef"><div class="_6a _5u5j"><div class="_6a _6b" style="height:100px"></div><div class="_6a _5u5j _6b"><div class="fsl fwb fcb">
```

then sanitize all regexp metacharacters in the text (see [Is it possible to escape regex metacharacters reliably with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed/29626460#29626460)) then convert the placeholder strings you used above to regexps:

```
_NOT_LESS_THAN_    -> [^<]+
_NOT_DOUBLE_QUOTE_ -> [^"]+
```

and then you can run sed -E to delete the text.

You might be better off with GNU awk though so you can set `RS` to the above text and that way you don't have to read the whole file into memory at one time.